# Facebook's malware solution

Tags: facebook, malware

Facebook didn't let me login today until I downloaded a portable Kaspersky scanner. I trust it and all, but the fact that Facebook said I had malware on my PC was weird. How can a webapp figure that out?

More importantly, it said the malware was posting stuff through facebook or whatever. Is this like the hack where the infected host posts like the ray ban sunglasses thing like this? http://www.welivesecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1.png

What if this is a load of BS that is merely installing google's tracking onto my PC? (probably not)

Edit: I'm really not trusting this, so I ended the process in task manager. Here's what came up: http://prntscr.com/cvl47l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IP was most likely flagged by Facebook as an account that was proliferating malicious posts (done via the malware on your computer).  Thus while they cant detect the malware outright they can detect that your IP has generated malicious traffic recently and redirect you accordingly.

Its like seeing a bunch of smoke down the road and calling the fire dpt before actually seeing the fire.  Given enough smoke you can be pretty sure that there will be fire.